# Преобразовать в число обратно .toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript

После преобразования числа методом .toLocaleString('ru') строка воспринимается как текст. Как преобразовать обратно в числовое значение?

Comment: Поставить перед строкой +

Comment: Не. Пробовал через parseFloat(value)  - получает только первый символ.

Comment: А само число угадайте сами!

Comment: 10 000 000   или 1 000 или  10 000, примерно так

Comment: [How do I convert String to Number according to locale (opposite of .toLocaleString)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/2881286)

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал в два шага:
1 .replace() - удалил пробелы
2 .parseFloat() - привел к числу

Comment: Не будет работать для языков, где разделитель не пробел

Comment: не сработает для дробных чисел, потому что в ru локали разделитель дробной части - запятая, а для parseFloat нужна точка

Comment: Нет дробных чисел